# Marketing Cloud Content Builder yellow highlighted code

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

We're moving from Marketing Cloud Classic to Content Builder. All of our emails are HTML paste. After creating the email in Content Builder and then close and reopen, we're noticing large blocks of the code highlighted in yellow. These emails have worked great in Classic -- Return Path and Litmus tested, as well as, live testing. Does this mean there is an issue with the way the  code works in Content Builder? This is a difficult transition for us based on the complexity of our sends. Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This highlighted code indicates Content Blocks that have been added to Content Areas in an email template.

To make changes to this code, you will need to edit it in the corresponding block widget (free form, image, text, etc).

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, then please accept my answer.